# Infopath form - I need to display a tooltip on a disabled button and remove it the tooltip when the button is enabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, sharepoint-list, infopath-form

I am working on an infopath form in which there's a submit button and have put a rule if any of the mandatory fields is blank then the button 'submit' is disabled. Hence, when all the mandatory fields are filled it gets auto-enabled. Here, I want to add a tooltip when the button 'submit' is disabled so that the end user knows that he has missed filling all the mandatory fields and when the submit button is enabled after the user fills all the mandatory fields the screentip/tooltip should be removed. Any suggestion on how this can be achieved is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tooltip for button**

It is doable and in fact it is a property of the button control. You can edit it to display the text you want.
[image]

**Mandatory fields**

For a submit button, the most straightforward way is using rules to hide the submit button before all the required fields are filled-in. Like the one I set here

[image]
[image]

And you can add validation rules on the required fields to display as notice.

More information about validation rules:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-rules-for-validation-fa530b5c-419f-4c03-a85f-d7f96cb9de95

We cannot remove the tooltip using rules as it is the property of the button control.